# how to link schema with another schema in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my problem i have a itemSchema and i am using this itemSchema as data type of listShecma Second Key value the listSchema has two propery first name and second items whose data type is [itemSchema] but when i create h new document and save it to lists collection it don't show up on console.log it shows undefinde i have added defailtItem(Sorry its a typo but leave it because i am using same name everywhere and it does not conatin any errors) on console.log defailtItem it show my array with javacript objhe itemSchema Here is Some code

```
const express = require("express");

const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const { default: mongoose } = require("mongoose");


// const date = require(__dirname + "/date.js");
// console.log(date);
const app = express();



// const items = ["Code", "Sleep", "Repeat"];

// const workitems =[];

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static('public'));
//Mongoose connection
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true); mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/todolistDB');
const db = mongoose.connection;

//mongoose item schema

const itemsSchema = {
     name: String
}

//mongoose model

const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemsSchema);

//creating items

const item1 = new Item ({
  name: "welcome to do the todolist"
});

const item2 = new Item ({
  name: "hit the + button to add the item"
});

const item3 = new Item ({
  name: "hit this to delete an item"
});

const defaultItems = [item1, item2, item3];

const listSchema = {
  name: String,
  item: [itemsSchema]
};

const List = mongoose.model("List", listSchema);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  // const day = date.getDate();

  Item.find({}, function(err, foundItems){
    if (foundItems.length === 0){
      Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function(err){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }else{
          console.log("sucessfully saved default items to the db");
        }
      });
      res.redirect("/");
    }else{
      res.render('list', {
        listTitle: "today",
        newListItems: foundItems
      });
    }
    
  });
   
});

app.get("/:customListName", function(req, res){
  const customListName = req.params.customListName;

const list =  new List({
  name: customListName,
  items: defaultItems
});

console.log(list.items);
list.save();

});
```

i want the customListName along with items